# Reorder NSTableView rows with Drag & Drop without NSTableViewDataSource

Tags: binding, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I would like to reorder my NSTableView rows using drag & drop, but all the examples I have found require the implementation of NSTableViewDataSource.  I'm populating my table with bindings, and would prefer to keep it that way.  Is it possible to implement NSTableViewDataSource and bindings side-by-side?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can combine bindings and the drag & drop methods of `NSTableViewDataSource`. Implement the drag & drop methods and don't implement the data methods. Use the methods of `NSArrayController` to reorder the data.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm feeling pretty dumb.  I had already tried what you suggested, but I cut and pasted some sample code that had a deprecated writeRowsWith method.  I only noticed when I option-clicked on the method and got no documentation link.  Duh...